# ajv validation of json schema is wrong in postman

Tags: json, postman, jsonschema, ajv

I have JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "regex": "some regex",
        "validationMessage": "some validation message"
    }
}
```

I use [this tool](https://jsonschema.net/) to build json schema.

Initialization is the following:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
    schema = {
  "definitions": {},
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "$id": "#/properties/data",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "regex": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/regex",
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        },
        "validationMessage": {
          "$id": "#/properties/data/properties/validationMessage",
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^(.*)$"
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Then I want to check json schema is valid

```
pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, {alpha: 123})).to.be.true;
});
```

And I see Test was passed.
What's wrong? And why is schema valid?

Further I'm going to replace `{alpha: 123}` with `JSON.parse(responseBody)`

Comment: How exactly are you using it in postman? As part of an OpenAPI definition document?

Comment: I can tell you why the instance is valid against the schema, but I can't tell you what you need to change unless you tell me WHY you expect valiation to fail. =]

Comment: I'm using Postman to test my API queries and I want to check if all fields (that are in schema) exist in response.

Comment: @A.Gladkiy Did the answer I provided help?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just need to include required fields and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing it to something like this:

```
var Ajv = require('ajv'),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console, allErrors: true}),
    schema = {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "data"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "regex",
            "validationMessage"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "regex": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            },
            "validationMessage": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "^(.*)$"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

pm.test('Schema is valid', function() {
    pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, { alpha: 123 }), JSON.stringify(ajv.errors)).to.be.true;
});
```

I added the `allErrors` option to `Ajv` and exposed those in the test. I also amended your schema slightly to add in required keys for the objects.

I tested this will an object hardcoded in the test but also with a mocked response.